# Как реализовать метод ToType интерфейса IConvertable?

Tags: c#, интерфейс

Я бы хотел увидеть пример реализации для любой пользовательской структуры

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот простой пример

```
object IConvertible.ToType(Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider)
{
    if (!hasValue)
    {
        //Если пришёл null
        // Или выбросить исключение
        // Или вернуть Null
    }
    //Отправляй данные в свой метод, и делай с ними что хочешь
    return Convert.ChangeType(value, conversionType, provider);
}
```